# JAVA,Как сделать , чтоб ID начинался с 1000 mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

Делаю проект на java добавления студентов в бд.У меня есть уже готовая таблица . подключение к базе, кнопкa "инсерт"  . И мне нужно во время добавление , чтоб ид начинался с 1000... 
я читал что то по поводу Alter table tbl auto_increment=1000 но я не знаю когда его надо заюзать . помогите пожалуйста. заранее спасибо. 
П,С, таблица уже готова .Создал ее вручную в phpmyadmin , без помощи кода.

Comment: alter table надо использовать один раз, после создания таблицы

Comment: НУ я понимаю ,но я не знаю куда его прописать и как , чтоб он работал . в этом проблема((((((((таблицу же я создаю сам вручную в phpmyadmin. (делаю проект в neatbeans на java)

Comment: В том же phpmyadmin есть окно для ввода текста sql-запросов. вот в нем и выполнять.

Comment: Ок , сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Все получилось